# Find index of most recent DateTime in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe that includes a column of datetimes, past and future. Is there a way to find the index of the most recent datetime?

I can *not* assume that each datetime is unique, nor that they are in order.

In the event that the most recent datetime is not unique, all the relevant indeces should be returned.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt

df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
# Create datetime column
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['Time'].astype(str))
print(df['datetime'])

Out[1]: 
0   2021-02-13 09:00:00
1   2021-02-13 11:00:00
2   2021-02-13 12:00:00
3   2021-02-13 15:00:00
4   2021-02-13 18:00:00
5   2021-02-13 16:45:00
6   2021-02-13 19:00:00
7   2021-02-13 19:00:00
8   2021-02-13 20:30:00
9   2021-02-14 01:30:00
Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: `df['datetime'].idxmax()` ?

Comment: @anky this does not work if the dataframe contains datetimes in the future. I want the most recent.

Comment: I don't think that is related to future problem, but duplicate datetimes. Can you try 

df['datetime'].max() which should give you a scalar string which you can filter the original df aginast?

Comment: @anky this returns an error

Comment: My bad, `df.loc[(pd.to_datetime('today') -df['datetime']).dt.days.ge(0),'datetime'].idxmax()`

Comment: @BingWang yes I think that would fix the duplicates issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**unique datetimes...**

a convenient option would be to use [`get_loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) method of [`DatetimeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html). Ex:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': pd.to_datetime(['2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-02-14'])})

# today is 2021-2-13, so most recent would be 2021-2-1:
pd.DatetimeIndex(df['datetime']).get_loc(pd.Timestamp('now'), method='pad')
# 1
```

You could also set the datetime column as index, simplifying the above to `df.index.get_loc(pd.Timestamp('now'), method='pad')`

---

**duplicates in datetime column...**

The datetime index method shown above won't work here. Instead, you can obtain the value first an *then* get the indices:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': pd.to_datetime(['2021-02-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-02-14'])})

# most recent datetime would be 2021-2-1 at indices 0 and 2
mr_date = df['datetime'].loc[(df['datetime'] - pd.Timestamp('now') <= pd.Timedelta(0))].max()
mr_idx = df.index[df['datetime'] == mr_date]

mr_idx
# Int64Index([0, 2], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: The most recent is not neccessarily the nearest

Comment: @lhmarsden: very good point! instead of 'nearest', use 'pad' (see the docs I linked).

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work if there are 2 datetimes that are the same, and both the most recent.

Comment: @lhmarsden: another good point ^^ - added on option how you could handle that.

Comment: Great, change ```pd.Timestamp('2021-2-13')``` to ```pd.Timestamp('now')``` and I'll mark it ask accepted!

Answer (score 2):

For excluding the future dates, you can compare with todays date then filter them out, then take `idxmax`

```
df.loc[(pd.to_datetime('today').day -df['datetime'].dt.day).ge(0),'datetime'].idxmax()
```

Comment: Does idxmax() returns  ALL indices if not unique ?   I guess not.  pandas API reference for [idxmax](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html#pandas.DataFrame.idxmax) states that it returns index of **first occurrence** of maximum over requested axis.

Comment: @SeaBean no you are correct, I was assuming OP wanted just 1 index. If you want all index using this method you can get `df.loc[(pd.to_datetime('today').day -df['datetime'].dt.day).ge(0),'datetime'].max()` then compare equality `==`  with the `datetime` column followed by boolean indexing

Comment: @anky This seems to return the wrong datetime (in your comment) or index (in your answer) when there are duplicate datetimes that are both the most recent

Comment: @lhmarsden try `df[df['datetime'].eq(df.loc[(pd.to_datetime('today').day -df['datetime'].dt.day).ge(0),'datetime'].max())].index` ? Bu most recent you mean most recent date or most recent datetime? if the latter, this comment should work